# Behaviour of DefWindowProc WinApi

Tags: windows, winapi, wm-paint

Can somebody explain why with DefWindowProc everything is ok, but if I remove it, the string "Hello windows" appears on screen without window and any buttons? "UpdateWindow" sends to window procedure WM_PAINT message, so why the text is displayed but creation of window is skipped?

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK proc1 (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("Program");
HWND hwnd1;
MSG msg1;
WNDCLASS wndclass1;

wndclass1.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wndclass1.lpfnWndProc = proc1;
wndclass1.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndclass1.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndclass1.hInstance = hInstance;
wndclass1.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndclass1.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndclass1.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
wndclass1.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndclass1.lpszClassName = szAppName;

RegisterClass (&wndclass1);

hwnd1 = CreateWindow (  szAppName,
                        TEXT ("My window"),
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL );
ShowWindow (hwnd1, iCmdShow);
UpdateWindow (hwnd1);
while ( GetMessage(&msg1, NULL, 0, 0) )
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg1);
    DispatchMessage(&msg1);
};
return msg1.wParam;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK proc1 (HWND hwnd1, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
 switch (message)
 {
 case WM_CREATE:
    return 0 ;
 case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd1, &ps) ;
    GetClientRect (hwnd1, &rect) ;
    DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("Hello windows"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
    EndPaint (hwnd1, &ps) ;
    return 0 ;
 case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage (0) ;
    return 0 ;
};
 return DefWindowProc (hwnd1, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you omit `DefWindowProc` then you are saying "For all messages I did not handle above, do nothing." Which means that a lot of messages like "Please draw the buttons" get handled as "do nothing." Result: No buttons. [Pass all unhandled messages to DefWindowProc](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/04/25/583093.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i know that WM_PAINT just paints the client area, which hasn't be created without DefWindowProc during the ShowWindow fuction call.

Answer (score 6):

Not all window messages require processing.  But if you remove the DefWindowProc() call then certain messages that *should* be processed don't get processed.  Like WM_NCPAINT, which draws the window frame.  And WM_ERASEBKGND, which draws the window background.  Which are things that DefWindowProc() knows to do well, in no small part assisted by the WNDCLASS you created for the window and the window style flags you passed in the CreateWindowEx() call.

So sure, remove the call and you won't see a frame nor a background.  And many, many other things that a window knows how to do without your help.  DefWindowProc() implements the default behavior of a window.  Your window procedure gives it non-default behavior.